# Where can the latest API documentation be found?

Tags: python, scripting

Some of my scripts scripts are broken e.g.

```
bpy.ops.pose.armature_layers(layers=sel_layers) # 2.6 api
```

has been (unnecessarily) renamed to

```
bpy.ops.pose.bone_layers(layers=sel_layers) # 2.7
```

In the 2.71 RC1

```
bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert(type='BUILTIN_KSI_LocRot')
```

leads to an error:

```
TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties:  enum "BUILTIN_KSI_LocRot"
 not found in ('Available', 'WholeCharacter')
```

And seems no longer to respect the bone/armature layers.

The latest documentation I found is:

http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_5/

which is not accessible from the navigation pages from blender.org, manipulating the version part of the URL neither works (tried 2_71, 2_71RC1, 2_71_RC1).

Where can the 2.71 API be found?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Update

You can now use http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/ to link to current API documentation. The difference from the old redirect is you can now link to specific parts, search results, etc. on the latest docs.

You can still specify a specific version if needed, e.g.
http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/ goes to the 2.76 specific documentation.

---

### Origonal answer

[This url](http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc/) is always redirected to the latest API documentation.

It redirects to `http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_*version*`

Comment: This link is so useful! When searching online for anything Blender, the results are so polluted with information about old versions (esp. 2.4 wiki links), so this link will be treasured. I wonder if there is a good way for the Blender Foundation to modify the structure of their online wiki and docs to reduce the difficulty in finding up to date info via a Google search.

Answer (score 7):

**Help -> Python API Reference**
Takes you to the API documentation page for the version of Blender you're running (which is mostly what you want).

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation hosted online](http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc/) for blender's python api docs is generated from blender's source code. While you will most likely find it awkward to search through the source code for the information you want, you can generate the latest api docs at any time similar to how you can build your own version of blender from source.

Blender uses sphinx to generate the api documentaion. Details of generating the [api docs is here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/API/Generating_API_Reference).