# What is the best Blender Python API reference?

Tags: python

I keep happening across information that seems blatantly wrong, and it makes me wonder if error messages are terrible or if it's the documentation.  Here's an example:

> However, while the script runs you may want to access the updated values.
>
> This can be done by calling bpy.types.Scene.update after modifying values which recalculates all data that is tagged to be updated.

This is quoted from the ["Gotchas" page](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_62_0/info_gotcha.html).

Upon following that advice...

> AttributeError: type object 'Scene' has no attribute 'update'

Just to be clear, the documentation authors [seem pretty convinced that it does](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_62_0/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.update).

Most of the bad information I've found so far comes from forum posts some place where a user just guessed at how to do something off the top of their head.  However, the official docs aren't really helpful for practical tasks, and seem to have bad information lurking about as well.

Comment: `types` is only used for documentation. See [this page](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html?highlight=Note%20that%20bpy.types.bpy_struct%20is%20not%20actually%20available%20from%20within%20blender,%20it%20only%20exists%20for%20the%20purpose%20of%20documentation.) Also, the 2.62 docs are pretty old by now. [This link](http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc/) always redirects to the latest version.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you very much.  If you post that as an answer, I can uptick it so others see it more easily.  Learning Python through the Blender API can be confusing due to the abundance of old documentation out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `types` module [is only used for documentation](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html?highlight=Note%20that%20bpy.types.bpy_struct%20is%20not%20actually%20available%20from%20within%20blender,%20it%20only%20exists%20for%20the%20purpose%20of%20documentation.).
See [this page](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70a_release/info_api_reference.html) for tips on finding actual datapaths.

Make sure you are using the latest API documentation too, see [Where can the latest API documentation be found?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12266/599)