# Changing viewport shading with python

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view

I am trying to change the viewport shading to `"RENDERED"` with python, but I can't seem to figure out how.

It seems `like bpy.types.SpaceView3D.viewport_shade = "RENDERED"` should do it, but this doesn't work and doesn't even give a context error.

Comment: bpy.types is only used for documentation. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15434/599

Comment: ok, so is there a way to change it? @gandalf3

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to specify which 3D view you want to access.

For example, this will iterate through all the areas in the current screen and set any 3D views to rendered shading:

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas: # iterate through areas in current screen
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for space in area.spaces: # iterate through spaces in current VIEW_3D area
            if space.type == 'VIEW_3D': # check if space is a 3D view
                space.viewport_shade = 'RENDERED' # set the viewport shading to rendered
```

---

### Update

Alternatively, you could also do the following:

```
import bpy

area = next(area for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D')
space = next(space for space in area.spaces if space.type == 'VIEW_3D')
space.viewport_shade = 'RENDERED'  # set the viewport shading
```

Instead of looping through the whole `bpy.context.screen.areas`, etc, the `next()` method returns `area` as soon as it finds `area.type == 'VIEW_3D'`. This doesn't really affect performance for this example but it's a better way of achieving the same result. Plus, it looks neater!

Comment: thanks! I guessed it was space compliant, because you can't activate it from anywhere but there. I just couldn't find a list of spaces. Thanks alot!

Comment: is there a way to do this in the game engine? say when you start the game it will always go into the specified shading instead of what ever shading you had when editing the game.

Comment: I'm getting *'SpaceView3D' object has no attribute 'viewport_shade'* in 2.80. There is a `shading` attribute, but it is read-only.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/124427/68286 works - uses `space.shading.type`

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer for 2.8+ and multi-window

```py
import bpy


for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
    for area in window.screen.areas: # iterate through areas in current screen
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            for space in area.spaces: # iterate through spaces in current VIEW_3D area
                if space.type == 'VIEW_3D': # check if space is a 3D view
                    space.shading.type = 'SOLID'
```

Answer (score 1):

context did not work for me.  Check this out if you are facing the same issue.

[Blender 2.8 : python code to switch shading mode (between wireframe and solid mode)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124347/blender-2-8-python-code-to-switch-shading-mode-between-wireframe-and-solid-mo/267874#267874)