# Toggle Wireframe

Tags: python

How to do toggle wireframe in python?

[image]

```
import bpy


for area in bpy.context.workspace.screens[0].areas:
    for space in area.spaces:
        if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            space.overlay.show_wireframes = True
```

How to make switching two state on and off?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124347/blender-2-8-python-code-to-switch-shading-mode-between-wireframe-and-solid-mo

Comment: With regards to the overlay setting note batFINGER's link but `space.overlay.show_wireframes = True` instead of `space.shading.type = my_shading`

Comment: @Ratt 
Thanks! Working fine, but how to make switching two state on and off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not operator:

```
space.overlay.show_wireframes = not space.overlay.show_wireframes
```