# Just want to set viewport to wireframe from script

Tags: python

Not sure how best to do this...

I have a very simple question. When I click on the solid view icon in the window I see the console shows:

```
bpy.context.space_data.shading.type = 'WIREFRAME'
```

But when I add that to the Text Script window:

```
import bpy
bpy.context.space_data.shading.type = 'WIREFRAME'
```

It of course doesn’t run because it doesn’t have the proper context.
I also tried:

```
import bpy

prev_type = bpy.context.area.type
bpy.context.area.type = 'VIEW_3D'
bpy.context.space_data.shading.type = 'SOLID'
bpy.context.area.type = prev_type
```

which doesn’t throw an error, but doesn’t work either. I know it must be something simple, but how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Screen is divided into areas.**

An areas active space, matches area type.

2nd script will set the 3d view in that space to solid shading, change text editor to 3d view to confirm.

To set 3dviews  in context screen, find them first

```
spaces3d = [a.spaces.active for a in context.screen.areas if a.type == 'VIEW_3D']
for s in spaces3d: 
    s.shading.type = 'SOLID'
```

If there are more than one view 3d open, you may wish to only set the largest area, can sort the list by area area `(a.width * a.height)`

Comment: [This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/124347/31447) could benefit from this answer too.

Comment: Cheers, did a cursory search, ,  close enough to dupe to mark as dupe don't you think

Comment: Thanks, how would I use only one (any one) of multiple VIEW_3D areas? Do I set a counter and check it in the for loop, or is there a simpler way?

Comment: `spaces3d[0]` is the first.  `s = spaces3d.pop()` is the last "popped off" the list.  See python docs on  `list` type.