# Setting camera clip end via Python

Tags: python, scripting, camera

Is there a Python command that will allow me to set the camera clip end for viewing my objects in Blender (via scripting)? According to http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_69_release/bpy.context.html the "bpy.context.space_data" variable is *read-only*.

Comment: Note that those API docs are for blender 2.69. See [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12266/599) for the latest version.

Answer (score 11):

`bpy.context.space_data` is read-only, but it's *properties* are not.

### For the active scene camera

```
context.scene.camera.data.clip_end
```

This gets the `clip_end` value for the active camera from the current scene, assuming there is one. If the current scene doesn't have an active camera, then `context.scene.camera` is `None` and this will raise an `AttributeError`.

### For the viewport:

```
for a in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if a.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for s in a.spaces:
            if s.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                s.clip_end = <your value>
```

This iterates through all areas in the current screen until it finds a 3D view, then iterates through all spaces in the 3D view until it finds a 3D view space, which is the object containing the [`clip_end`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_4/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.clip_end) property.

Comment: This one came up as a link in new post. The camera object, and its data  (from `bpy.data.cameras`)  may not always have the same name, suggest using `cam = context.scene.camera.data`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the same data for a driver.

[image]